# Use the Google Reviews API to add a review

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way I can use the [Google Reviews API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/reviews) to write a review on the Google Play store on a users behalf?

The only methods that I see are `get`, `list` and `reply` that are useful to me only once a user posts a review.

If not is there any other package/toolkit that allows me to do this?